# Multi-module Spring project: override a resource file in test

Tags: java, spring, maven, classloader

I have a Spring project with the following structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── core-module
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       │       ├── applicationContext.xml
│       │       └── file.xml
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           └── resources
│               ├── file.xml
│               └── foo.xml
└── web-module
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   └── java
        └── test
            └── java
```

In my applicationContext.xml file, I have the following import:
`<import resource="classpath:file.xml" />`

In production I want to use the `file.xml` defined in `main`, and during tests I want to use the one defined in the `test` folder; it's actually what is happenning when I run the tests of the `core-module`.

However, when I run the tests of the `web-module`, this is not the case, the file used is the one of the `main` folder.
How to perform what I want?

Some notes:

- `web-module` has a `test-jar` dependency to `core-module`, so tests resources are included;
- if I go inside the `target` directory, the `file.xml` is the good one in the `test-classes` folder;
- when running `web-module` tests, if I put a breakpoint in the Spring code, then a `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` on `file.xml` returns the one defined in `main`, but if I run the same method on the `foo.xml` file it returns me the only one available in the `test` folder, so both files seems to be present, but it acts as if the `main` takes over the `test` resource...

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah I think it does a classpath scan and takes the first one it encounters.

Comment: What is your reason for using XML configuration? Is this a legacy project?

Comment: @YassinHajaj You're right... but test resources should appear first in the classpath. :(

Comment: @chrylis I prefer to use both, however I'm not sure it's the debate here. But thank you for your help.

Comment: It's relevant because placeholder configuration does vary between XML and JavaConfig.